# Strictly monotonically increasing sequences of natural numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory, natural-numbers

I have several questions with regards to these sequences:

1. What is the cardinality of the set of all such sequences?

   I assume that it is equal to the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$, is that correct?
2. Consider those sequences which can be expressed with a finite formula.

   Is the cardinality of the set of those sequences equal to the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$?
3. Are there any other sequences which cannot be expressed with a finite formula?

   I have a feeling that this question might lead to a paradox, hence cannot be answered.

   Nevertheless, my intuition tells me that there have to be infinitely many such sequences.

   How can we prove that, and how can we find the cardinality of the set of those sequences?

---

Examples of a finite formula:

1. $A_n=n$
2. $An=2n$
3. $An=$ the $n$th prime
4. $A_1=1,A_2=2,A_n=A_{n-1}+A_{n-2}$
5. $A_n=\begin{cases}
              n+1&\text{$   1\leq{n}\leq   10$}\\
              n+2&\text{$  11\leq{n}\leq  100$}\\
              n+3&\text{$ 111\leq{n}\leq 1000$}\\
              n+4&\text{$1111\leq{n}\leq10000$}\\
              n+5&\text{       otherwise      }\\
    \end{cases}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are correct that there are $2^{\aleph_0}$ strictly increasing sequences. An easy way of seeing this is to note that given a set $A\subseteq\Bbb N$ you can define a function $f$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $\chi_A(n)=f(n+1)-f(n)-1$.

For the second question, and simultaneously the third, "finite formula" is a very ambiguous term. What is the language in which we are allowed to express this formula? If the language only includes $+$ and $\cdot$ and $\leq$, or any countable number of symbols, then there are only countably many finite formulas in that language to begin with, not all even define functions or increasing functions.

But if you don't specify the language, why not take the language which includes a function symbol for every possible function from $\Bbb N$ to itself? And axioms which describe the behavior of these functions on every natural number completely. In that case, each function can be described using a very short formula.

So the second and third questions, which are tied together, cannot be fully answered without specifying what a "finite formula" means exactly. If we play the naive assumption game, then the answer is that there are only countably many finite formulas, so "almost" all functions are undefinable.

---

**EDIT:**

In the comments the OP points out that every real number can be used as part of the language. This means that in fact every function from $\Bbb N$ to itself can be defined with a finite formula, and a real number as a parameter.

To see this, just consider real numbers $r$ whose expansion in a fixed basis includes only $1$ and $0$ (which exist in all bases, but there are other tricks to use here). Now use the $0$ as delimiters for the blocks of $1$, and just "read off" the length of the $n$-th block as the value for $f_r(n)$.

Other wonderful ways of encoding and decoding exist. For example continued fractions.

Comment: You can use any real number (just as long as the combined formula generates a strictly monotonically increasing sequence of natural numbers), so there are infinitely uncountable many symbols.

Comment: I've added to accommodate your comment.

Comment: Oh, so you just encode every possible sequence using some "corresponding" real number?

Comment: Yeah, that's the general idea. There are plenty of ways to do that, too. Especially if you can internalize induction.

Comment: How can you be sure that every real number by itself can be expressed with a finite formula? I realize that many of them can be expressed with a finite formula (as a root of some rational-coefficient polynomial, as an infinite sum, as an infinite product, etc). I guess that all algebraic and infinitely many transcendental can be expressed that way. But how can you be sure that it can be done for **every possible** real number?

Comment: If the real numbers are constants in your language, then $x=r$ is a formula defining $r$; and $r$ itself is a term evaluated as $r$.

Comment: Well, that's a bit tricky now, isn't it? How can they be represented as constants? Do you mean $r_1,r_2,r_3\ldots$? But there are uncountably many of them.

Comment: I don't understand the issue; and I think that you have some gap in your understanding of what are "symbol" and "formula" in this context. You allow me to use any real number, why do I need to assume that I can index them using the natural numbers somehow for this?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I need to find a way to rephrase that. But using a real number, as far as I'm concerned, is by writing it down somehow. Perhaps the question should be reduced to **real numbers** which cannot be represented with a finite formula (are there any, how many of them, etc).

Comment: Again, comes the question. Finite formula **in what language**? If the language already includes all the real numbers as constants, then every real number can be defined.

Comment: OK, I understand that. Thank you very much :)

Comment: What does the $\chi_A(n)$ notation mean?

Comment: @ruakh: The indicator function of $A$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Every subset of $\mathbb{N}$ defines such a sequence, so there is continuum of them as you say.
2. Every finite formula contains a finite number of symbols, which are chosen from countable set. So it's a countable sum of countable sets, then it's aleph zero.
3. The answers above prove that there are such sequences. The cardinality will then be continuum, because no uncountable set can be divided into two countable sets.

Comment: "Which are chosen from a countable set" - feel free to use any real number from the uncountable set $\mathbb{R}$ (just as long as the combined formula generates a strictly monotonically increasing sequence of natural numbers).